# Isometric mapping of two subsets in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

Let (M,d) be a metric space, and M1, M2 be two subspace of M.

Edit: I forgot to mension that both M1 and M2 are dense.

Suppose we have

$f: M \rightarrow M$
and we know f is an isometric mapping from M1 to M1, i.e.,
$$
d(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b)
$$
for any $a,b \in M1$.

Suppose we also have
$$
d(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b)
$$
for any $a \in M1$ and $b \in M2$.

The question is : can we say that f is an isometric mapping of $M1\cup M2$?

In other words, is it possible to show that
$$
d(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b)
$$
for any $a,b \in M1\cup M2$.

I think it is true in Euclidean space, but I have no idea how to do it in a general metric space.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take $M_1$ the origin in the euclidean plane and take $M_2$ the unit circle. Consider a map which contracts in the direction of the vector $(0,1)$ while keeping the absolute values fixed.

Comment: I see the counterexample. What if M1 and M2 are both dense? I think in this case it holds in euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

$M_1=\{a\}$, $M_2=\{b,c\}$, $f(a)=a, f(b)=f(c)=b$, $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was wondering, what if we have M1 and M2 are both dense sets? I think in that case the statement is true in Euclidean space.